# Насколько затратны операции атачинга шэйдеров и линковки программы?

Tags: opengl, opengles

Создал кастомную сцену, которая прорисовывается `opengl`-ем. При этом для прорисовки каждого кадра приходится применять по 3 пары шейдеров. Соответственно задался вопросом: много ли я теряю в производительности каждый раз присоеденяя шэйдеры и линкуя прогу?

Comment: что Вы называете линковкой?

Comment: перед стартом вы компилируете шейдеры, а во время отрисовки переключаете через useProgram

Comment: в котексте линковки программы opengl

Comment: да, компилирую, конечно, только один раз

Comment: ну можно все затолкать в один шейдер, но не знаю есть ли в этом реальный профит, но если у Вас стандартный кейс с g-buffer и post-processing тогда все равно придется переключать программы

Comment: еще получать unformLocation нужно один раз а на в рамках отрисовки

Comment: Что-то вы странное делаете. Обычно линкуют тоже один раз, при запуске. А потом переключают программы через `glUseProgram`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а разве можно линковать к программе сразу несколько шейдеров?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat или вы имеете ввиду, что создается несколько инстанций программ, между которыми потом просто переключаются?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch *"разве можно линковать к программе сразу несколько шейдеров"* Обычно линкуют только вершинный и фрагментный, ничего другого я не предлагаю. Но можно линковать один и тот же шейдер к разным программам. Да, я предлагаю при запуске насоздавать программ и сразу слинковать каждую, а потом только переключаться между ними.